# No launcher activity found..The launch will only sync the application package on the device

Tags: android

i am working in android using eclipse. page navigation.
 but i counldn't see my app on emulator.
 I have posted my manifest file and the related errors.
 plssss help me plsss.

Manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.navigate"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
                android:name="com.example.navigate.SecondScreenActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name = "android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>



            </activity>

         </application>

    </manifest>
```

Errors:

```
    [2014-02-02 16:35:53 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for C:\Users\swathi\workspace\Navigate\AndroidManifest.xml: Attribute name "filter" associated with an element type "intent" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
    [2014-02-02 16:35:53 - Navigate] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
    [2014-02-02 16:36:01 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for C:\Users\swathi\workspace\Navigate\AndroidManifest.xml: Element type "action" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
    [2014-02-02 16:36:01 - Navigate] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
    [2014-02-02 16:36:16 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for C:\Users\swathi\workspace\Navigate\AndroidManifest.xml: The element type "intentfilter" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</intentfilter>".
    [2014-02-02 16:36:16 - Navigate] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
```

Comment: Try inserting a space here **"/>** to read so **" />** (you have two of these)

Answer (score 0):

try using this `.SecondScreenActivity` instead of "com.example.navigate.SecondScreenActivity"